# Charging cellphone from dynamo - safety risks

Tags: charging, cellphone, alternator

I want to make a dynamo charger to charge multiple smartphones at once. I have figured out the schematics, but before I put a smartphone in it I want to be sure it will not destroy it.

**Schematics:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSwE9X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So my biggest concerns are:

1. voltage - I hope the converter and capacitors will keep it stable
2. current - I think that smartphones control their charging current by themselves, or not?
3. what will happen, if I stop turning the dynamo? The capacitors will hold the charge for a very small moment, and then what? Will the buck converter just shut down?
4. what will happen, if I will be turning the dynamo too slow/too fast?

**Thanks for your advice.** I tried searching google, but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: I want to meet the person who can produce >500 watts with a hand-cranked dynamo. I won't be shaking their hands, though.

Comment: I can push 500Watts continuously on an elliptical cross trainer.  Can't do it just with my hands, though.

Comment: @NickJohnson If there's people that can pull an 18 wheeler over 5m, lift up 100's of kg etc, I'm sure there's people that can generate 500W+ mechanical power with two arms. I think many pro rowers come at least near that range, though it is not just hands, that is where they have the paddles...

Comment: With a known dynamo characteristics, For others, does using a rechargeable battery helps in this case?

Comment: Well it is not hand-cranked in that meaning, I wanted to say it is human-powered - it is connected to a bike, and I never expect it to output 500W - so far, I got 7 amps of current maximum... (sorry for misunderstanding)

Comment: 12V*7A is still an awful lot, and a lot more than any common bicycle dynamo I've seen. Make sure you know the full specs of the device. (About 6W output seems common). Also, make sure you get **DC** to feed into the converter. Many dynamos output **AC** at varying frequencies.

Comment: It is a car alternator, connected to a bike. However it has integrated diode bridge, so it outputs DC.

Comment: Those 22mF capacitors look rather small. Make sure you have a flywheel or extra weight on the rim of the bike to ensure smooth power delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when the generator rotates too slow or too fast depends on your buck converter. If in all cases the maximum voltage out of the generator (only you know/can-test that) is below the maximum voltage of the buck converter: that's okay.

If you go too slow the buck converter may drop its output voltage and get hot, or just shut down, that's up to the buck converter, again, only you know that.

When you stop the voltage will fall gradually, for a short time the buck converter will be operating outside of its specs, but if you make sure that is a short enough time (less than a second or three) most likely the converter and any attached phones will survive. Most standard buck converter designs can handle a short while outside of their comfort zone, with respect to minimum voltage and most, if not all, phones will know to stop charging when the voltage goes below 4.4V, because of their regulation internally.

With respect to charging current: Yes, all phones must handle that themselves, else they are not allowed to be USB spec. If you want your phones to charge fast, in fact, you may need to short the two data pins of the USB plugs together to let them know it's okay to ask for 1A or more. Some brands also do something with resistors (Apple for anything above 350mA, Samsung for anything above 1A, etc). You may want to look up "{BRAND_NAME} DIY Charger Schematic 2A" (or 1A, or whatever you want to offer, or no current in the search, as most DIY's are 1A+) for advice about tactics for your specific brands that you want to support.

Whether your voltages stay in range with the components you choose is not up to us to answer. You know what you are using and how much total power the phones are allowed to take in your design, so we cannot possibly comment without any information about *exact* specifics about what you use and what you want.

You can add an "under voltage lockout" that turns off the buck converter, if the converter itself doesn't have that, just before your 12V generator drops to its absolute minimum voltage. How to do that depends a lot on the specifics mentioned earlier and should be asked, with the relevant details, type numbers and datasheets, in a new question just about that part of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you both solved my question! And just to make sure, are you aware of any other risks this may have except the ones already mentioned here?

Comment: Eeehhh, appart from @hanno-binder 's advice to use a TVS to catch spikes when things stop pulling current, I think you're good to do an experiment, but the first hours use something as a load that you can afford to throw away (something else that uses a few amps at 5V) and keep an eye on everything. Bare-generator schemes are risky if you do them the first time. Oh, and make sure your capacitors are rated for 1.5x the peak voltage you expect. You are going to underestimate something, a 22mF capacitor that does boom is very bad.

Comment: Back-feed protection is likely to be needed.

Comment: @Andyaka A good point, but I'm not sure I agree with 'likely'. On the basis of everything being DC in the proposed schematic, so the only backfeeding I can see happening is from such enabled phones back through the buck or into others, but in both my Androids I need to enable that at each connect/disconnect of a data-enabled device. It can't hurt to add extra diodes if the power can be missed, but likely to be needed may be overstating it, I feel. Unless I have a blind spot for something in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
voltage - I hope the converter and capacitors will keep it stable
```

The converter should do that. Just make sure it can handle the max. voltage from the dynamo (plus some safety margin). At low load, a "12V" dynamo may generate more than 12V.

```
current - I think that smartphones control their charging current by themselves, or not?
```

Yes, they do, no problem here. Just make sure you *never* exceed 5.25V.

```
what will happen, if I stop turning the dynamo? [...] Will the buck converter just shut down?
```

Nothing bad will happen. The input and output voltage will "slowly" drop during some milliseconds. Common (cheap) converters just try to keep the output stable, and when the input gets too low, their output gets lower too. It shouldn't be a problem for a USB device to survive low voltage, especially if it's only temporary.

```
what will happen, if I will be turning the dynamo too slow/too fast?
```

Too fast may yield higher-than-normal output voltage of the dynamo, as does a no/low load situation. Make sure your converter can handle that voltage as input, or put safety devices in place, e.g. a [TVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode) and a fuse.